# Add data to a json file using Talend

Tags: json, talend

I have the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "date": "29/11/2021",
        "Name": "jack",

    },
    {
        "date": "30/11/2021",
        "Name": "Adam",

    },
        "date": "27/11/2021",
        "Name": "james",

    }
]
```

Using Talend, I wanna add 2 lines to have something like:

```
[
    {
        "company": "AMA",
        "service": "BI",
        "date": "29/11/2021",
        "Name": "jack",
        

    },
    {
        "company": "AMA",
        "service": "BI",    
        "date": "30/11/2021",
        "Name": "Adam",

    },
        "company": "AMA",
        "service": "BI",    
        "date": "27/11/2021",
        "Name": "james",

    }
]
```

Currently, I use 3 components (tJSONDocOpen, tFixedFlowInput, tJSONDocOutput) but I can't have the right configuration of components in order to get the job done !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not comfortable  with json .

**Just do these steps :**

1. In the metaData just create a FileJson  like this then paste it in your job as a tFileInputJson

[image]

2. Your job design and mapping  would be

[image]

3. In your tFileOutputJson don't forget to change in the **name of the data block** "Data" with ""

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do there according to the Talend practices is read your JSON. Then extract each object of it, add your properties and finally rebuild your JSON in a file.

An efficient way to do this is using tMap componenent [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpiQR.png).

The first tFileInputJSON will have to specify what properties it has to read from the JSON [by setting your 2 objects in the mapping field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFaza.png).

Then the tMap will simply add 2 columns to your main stream, [here is an example with hard coded string values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTj78.png). Depending on you needs, this component will also offer you the possibility to assign dynamic data to your 2 new columns, it's a powerful tool for manipulating the structure of a data stream.

You will find more infos about this component in the official documentation : https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/7.3/tmap/tmap; especially the "tMap scenarios" part.

#### Note

Instead of using the tMap, if you are comfortable with Java, you can use a tjavaRow instead. Using this, you can setup your 2 new columns with whatever java code you want to put as long as you have defined the output schema of the component.

```java
output_row.Name = input_row.Name;
output_row.date = input_row.date;
output_row.company = "AMA";
output_row.service = "BI";
```